# my couter time gets reset on page load

Tags: javascript, php

recently i implemented a count timer for my shopping website that sets a limit of 24 hours when they create an order and not check out with a payment,so that counter reminds him/her that have to make a payment. The timer that is in our table is the start time and is adjusted by the current time up to 24 hours - after that, the order is cancelled.
Now i have a problem, when i reload the page the counter restarts from 24 hours this is my code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function startTimer(duration, display) {
var start = '<?php echo $pending_order_date;?>';
function timer() {
    // get the number of seconds that have elapsed since 
    // startTimer() was called
    diff = duration - (((Date.now() - start) / 1000) | 0);
    // does the same job as parseInt truncates the float
    minutes = (diff / 60) | 0;
    seconds = (diff % 60) | 0;

    if(minutes >= 60){
       hours = (minutes / 60) | 0;
       minutes = (minutes % 60) | 0;
    }else{
       hours = 0;
    }
    hours = hours < 10 ? "0" + hours : hours;
    minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
    seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

    display.textContent = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;

    if (diff <= 0) {
        // add one second so that the count down starts at the full duration
        // example 05:00 not 04:59
        start = Date.now() + 1000;
    }
};
// we don't want to wait a full second before the timer starts
timer();
setInterval(timer, 1000);
 }

window.onload = function () {
var twentyfourhour = 60 * 60 *24,
    display = document.querySelector('#time');
startTimer(twentyfourhour, display);
  };
</script>
```

Please see my code, i get the timestamp in php from my table and the count.
Your help would be appreciated.

Comment: You are going to have to store the time stamp between page calls

Comment: @ScottMarcus i am beginner so don't know much about please help

Comment: That's too much for a single answer on SO. Start to look at databases, localstorage, etc.

Comment: @patricksweeney are you have answer or just comment.

Answer (score 0):

You need to store your left off duration somewhere. localStorage seems to be better fit

```
function startTimer(duration, display) {
    var start = '<?php echo $pending_order_date;?>';
    function timer() {
        // get the number of seconds that have elapsed since 
        // startTimer() was called
        diff = duration - (((Date.now() - start) / 1000) | 0);
        // does the same job as parseInt truncates the float
        minutes = (diff / 60) | 0;
        seconds = (diff % 60) | 0;

        if(minutes >= 60){
           hours = (minutes / 60) | 0;
           minutes = (minutes % 60) | 0;
        }else{
           hours = 0;
        }
        hours = hours < 10 ? "0" + hours : hours;
        minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
        seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

        display.textContent = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;

        if (diff <= 0) {
            // add one second so that the count down starts at the full duration
            // example 05:00 not 04:59
            start = Date.now() + 1000;
        }
        localStorage.setItem('timer', diff);
    };
    // we don't want to wait a full second before the timer starts
    timer();
    setInterval(timer, 1000);
 }

window.onload = function () {
    var twentyfourhour = 60 * 60 *24,
    display = document.querySelector('#time');
    var timePassed = localStorage.getItem('timer');
    startTimer((typeof timer!=='undefined' ? timer : twentyfourhour), display);
  };
```

so each time your duration changes, it will update localStorage timer value. when you reload page, it will look for timer item in localStorage and will get that value, if it doesn't exist then will use 24 hrs. you may also add a controller to remove timer once it is expired, and store it with the order number or something so you can use multiple values. but this should give you an idea.

Comment: sir i store the datetime in databse and want to compare that datetime with current time and after minus show the time remainning how to do that without store every duration timer

Comment: well then instead of sending 24 hrs in initial call send the first difference `window.onload = function() { var duration = <?php echo date('u', strtotime($pending_order_date)) - time();?>; startTimer(duration, display);   }` this way you will send the time you recorded minus now to your function initially and counter will start from there.